# Are aluminum profiles dangerous?

Tags: side-effects, brain, neurology, air-quality, alzheimers

I am thinking about building racing rig from aluminium profiles. Something like this: 
[image]
<sup>Original image here: http://www.simracingmachines.com/images/builds/rig2014/IMG_1686s.jpg</sup>

I would like to have this construction in my bedroom, where I am sleeping. 
So, I am interested in, if those aluminium profiles should affect my health. I tried to use google, but all posts I have found were about aluminium and food, foil, kettles…

Many drivers are using AL profile. Is it possible to release aluminium particles into the air… or whether it's a good idea to have this rig in a room used for sleeping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General rule of thumb: Reduce the amount of dirt and dust in the air you breathe.

This question does currently not specify if those profiles are just handled and assembled in a bedroom. That should be fine.

However, implicitly one can read that as asking for: if those profiles get drilled and sawed and machine polished, then a certain amount of dust and particles will be produced, getting into the air and inhaled into the lungs. Not a good idea in general.

> Conversely, exposure to aluminium dust may possibly increase the risk of cardiovascular disease and dementia of the Alzheimer's type.
>    <sub>[Susan Peters et al.: "Long-term effects of aluminium dust inhalation", Occup Environ Med.2013 Dec;70(12):864-8](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24142983). doi: 10.1136/oemed-2013-101487.</sub>

This is covered with recommendations for occupational risks by several state level organisations, for example:

> HAZARD SUMMARY
>
> - Aluminum can affect you when breathed in.
> - Contact can irritate the skin and eyes.
> - Exposure to Aluminum can cause “metal fume fever.”
>     This is a flu-like illness with symptoms of metallic taste in the mouth, headache, fever and chills, aches, chest tightness and cough. The symptoms may be delayed for several hours after exposure and usually last for a day or two.
> - Exposure to fine dust can cause scarring of the lungs (pulmonary fibrosis) with symptoms of cough and shortness of breath.
> - Aluminum powder is a FLAMMABLE SOLID and a DANGEROUS FIRE HAZARD.
>
> <sub>[ALUMINUM - State of New Jersey Hazardous Substance Fact Sheet](http://nj.gov/health/eoh/rtkweb/documents/fs/0054.pdf)</sub>

One should also keep in mind:

> **Conclusions**
>   The hazards posed by metal dusts are real. Recent incidents have shown that improper handling of metal dusts can cost lives. Apart from this, inappropriate metal-dust handling poses health risks, property dam- age possibilities, and housekeeping/maintenance costs. The key to reducing metal-dust hazards is to first minimize dust generation whenever possible. For the dust that is generated, safe and proper containment and capture follows. The proper design of powder storage and handling systems is quintessential in this regard. For the dust that still manages to find egress from the main process and accumulate, effective housekeeping and maintenance becomes the next line of protection. Also, it is important to perform site assessments for dust-hazard potentials and implement strategies to minimize the risks.
>   <sub>[Understanding and Preventing Metal Dust Hazards - Jenike & Johanson](http://jenike.com/files/2013/09/IJPM_Article_11.13.pdf)</sub>

All of these findings and resulting recommendations are for occupational hazards and risks. Meaning that relatively large amounts of dust would be inhaled over quite a long time. A one-off project with limited dust producing capacity is far below the quantities discussed in these papers.

But it still is a risk and a messy procedure on top. A bedroom is for sleeping and should be kept clean. The cleaner the air the better.

Aluminium profiles are safe. Producing dust from them in a bedroom is not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Profiles are already sawed. It is all about screwing. I thought at first a spontaneous release to the air.

Comment: @PeterKosinski No solid metal releases anything into the air.